# Getting user's IP address through Cloudflare and Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, ip-address, cloudflare

I have a website in Azure, the website is routed through Cloudflare for extra protection.

Cloudflare adds a header `CF-Connecting-IP` which is supposed to be the client's IP address, however sometimes this gives a real IP address but most of the time I'm getting reserved IP addresses instead of the client's IP.

I tested it going to the website through my office internet and cloudflare returns a reserved IP address, however when I go to whatsmyip.org I get my real office IP address.

How can I make sure to always obtained the client's IP address unless of course they are behind a proxy or VPN.

Comment: Isn’t the IP address part of request headers off the client accessing your website..? Can you please provide code you use to get IP addresses..

Comment: Right now I just get the header with the cf-connecting-ip index which gives me the ip address, if is not set then I return null, the thing is that it always return something even if it is those reserved ip addresses

Comment: Interesting platform but do you feel comfortable it won't filter out half of your visitors? They seem to have great community and forum, try asking there..

Answer (score 7):

Based on *masoud ch's* answer, a .NET Core version could look like this using `IHttpContextAccessor` instead of `HttpRequestBase`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Linq;

namespace myproject.Extensions
{
    public static class HttpContextAccessorExtensions
    {
        public static string GetIpAddress(this IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"]))
                return accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"];

            var ipAddress = accessor.HttpContext.GetServerVariable("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                var addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
                if (addresses.Length != 0)
                    return addresses.Last();
            }

            return accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To use the extension in your controller do the following:

**HomeController.cs**

```
 private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor; 

 public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
 {
     _accessor = httpContextAccessor; // Dependency Injection:
 }

 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     var IP = _accessor.GetIpAddress());
     return View();
 }
```

Comment: How to get the port?

Comment: @sunnamed This is an entirely different question you are asking and not related to the OP. I am not sure what you want with the port in any case. See CF for supported headers (port is not one of them) https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/reference/http-request-headers/

`REMOTE_PORT` can be retrieved on your server.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the link that Terry Carmen posted in the only other answer (at the time of writing this) then you'll see that there are 2 headers that you can use to get the IP:

X-Forwarded-For and CF-Connecting-IP

I believe that X-Forwarded-For is the better one to use. Cloudflare will set this to the same value as CF-Connecting-IP if it isn't already present, otherwise they will maintain its value through to your server.

Consider this scenario:

User => SomeCloudProvider => Cloudflare => YourServer

In this scenario CF-Connecting-IP will be SomeCloudProvider because that's what's connecting to Cloudflare. But if SomeCloudProvider had added the User IP address in X-Forwarded-For then Cloudflare will preserve this and send it on to you (in the headers) so you can get the real IP address of the User.

X-Forwarded-For is a quasi-standard that all cloud providers, routers, switches etc. (that I've seen) will add or maintain.

Comment: it's actually X-Forwarded-For header that contains the actual IP, CF-Connecting-IP recently is empty

Answer (score 2):

X-Forwarded-For is a list of IP address, where the last one is most likely user's IP address.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-

> Example:
>
> X-Forwarded-For: 198.51.100.101,198.51.100.102,203.0.113.1
>
> In the examples above, 203.0.113.1 is the original visitor IP address
> and 198.51.100.101 and 198.51.100.102 are proxy server IP addresses
> provided to Cloudflare via the X-Forwarded-For header

We have to grab it, if it is present in the list, if not default to UserHostAddress. As a bonus, Cloudflare defines its own header for client IP address called CF-Connecting-IP. If you use Cloudflare look for it. If use some other cloud providers check for specific headers they might define. Example below should give you good general idea how to get user's IP address.

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static string GetIpAddress(this HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        if (request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"] != null)
            return request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"];

        var ipAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            var addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
                return addresses.Last();
        }

        return request.UserHostAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: you got the order reversed in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header - proxy IPs are appended, not prepended, so you need the first one instead of last

Answer (score 1):

They provide CF-Connect**ing**-IP, which is supposed to be correct.

I'm not sure what would be in CF-Connect**ion**-IP

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-

Comment: Here is a couple of reserved ip addresses Cloudflare is returning 241.7.216.18, 248.245.44.54, 240.31.14.8 241.43.18.136. These are obviously wrong. I read on cloudflare that we can add some entries to the server settings but I can't do this hosting my app on an Azure App service plan

Comment: The 241 net is reserved but not invalid like the local net addresses (10,192, 172, etc.) .It's used for multicast. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1112

Comment: Right, I know these  IPs are valid, the issue is cloudflare is not giving me the real ip even when I can verify it through whatsmyip.com

Comment: CF says they pass the IP in that header. If it's not right, there's nothing you can do except contact Cloudflare. It's possible they're seeing some other downstream router or appliance between you and them. Just because whatsmyip gets your real IP doesn't mean CF always gets it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ForwardedHeadersExtensions, cloudflare and azure also send `​​X-Forwarded-For` header. Btw almost all proxy send that

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

If there is no `X-Forwarded-For` header you can specify any header you want

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedForHeaderName = "custom-x-forwarded-for",
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

After that u can just resolve ip regular way,

```
var ip = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Comment: Not work for me